# Lazy list comprehension in Elixir?

Tags: stream, list-comprehension, elixir

Is there a way to make list comprehension lazy in Elixir? If not, is there a way to turn this into a `Stream`?

`my_list = for i <- (1..1000000), j <- (1..1000000), do: {i, j}`

This code snippet blows my program by taking too much memory.

I want to apply a filter, map and reduce on my_list.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

A comprehension is a flat map. So your code is equivalent to:

```
Stream.flat_map 1..1000000, fn i ->
  Stream.flat_map 1..1000000, fn j ->
    [{i, j}]
  end
end
```

I have proposed a "stream for" and "parallel for" for future Elixir versions, however it is pending some other improvements to the language.

Comment: Thanks, José! I knew you as the Elixir language creator, but you blew my mind answering all my SO questions on Elixir so far. I'm a big fan. I know you are not a human, and I mean it in the nicest possible way.